# Python : Data Cleaning to create Column - Row Pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dump data that is of the form : `A:a;B:b;C:c;D;d` and so on.
`A` is the column name while `a` is its corresponding value.
This is what I want the output too look like :

```
A B C D
a b c d
```

Comment: Sorry the question reformatted by expected output. 'A' has to be the column name and 'a' will be the value under A , 'B' will be column name and 'b' will be value and so on

Comment: `I have a dump data that is of the form` - it is long string like `s = A:a;B:b;C:c;D;d`  ? Or it is value of list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to dictionaries and then to `DataFrame`:

If input is string:

```
s = 'A:a;B:b;C:c;D:d'

d = dict([x.split(':') for x in s.split(';')])
print (d)
{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c', 'D': 'd'}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  a  b  c  d
```

If input is list:

```
L = ['A:a;B:b;C:c;D:d', 'A:a1;B:b1;C:c1;D:d1']

d1 = [dict([x.split(':') for x in s.split(';')]) for s in L]
print (d1)
[{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c', 'D': 'd'},
 {'A': 'a1', 'B': 'b1', 'C': 'c1', 'D': 'd1'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d1)
print (df)
    A   B   C   D
0   a   b   c   d
1  a1  b1  c1  d1
```

EDIT:

```
L = ['A:a;B:b;C:c;D:d;ee;tt', 'Turbina;Val;A:a1;B:b1;C:c1;D:d1;Another val']

v = []
for s in L:
    out = []
    counter=0
    for x in s.split(';'):
        splitted = x.split(':')
        if len(splitted) == 2:
            out.append(splitted)
        else:
            
            out.append((f'item{counter}', splitted[0]))
            counter += 1
    v.append(dict(out))
print (v)
[{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c', 'D': 'd', 'item0': 'ee', 'item1': 'tt'}, 
 {'item0': 'Turbina', 'item1': 'Val', 'A': 'a1', 'B': 'b1', 'C': 'c1', 'D': 'd1', 'item2': 'Another val'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(v)
print (df)
    A   B   C   D    item0 item1        item2
0   a   b   c   d       ee    tt          NaN
1  a1  b1  c1  d1  Turbina   Val  Another val
```

Comment: its dataset for hardware components i think the values are like ;Joint : Elbow;X:x and there are n number of rows for the same in an xml file. i hope that provides better are understanding of the use case

Comment: @saimkhan - Unfortuntaly not understand what is input data. List? String? Xml?

Comment: its an XML; here is a sample :TURBINE:  GAS ; MAKE: M/S HITACHI ; MODEL: H-25

Comment: @saimkhan - Super, pleas edit answer with your code for processing xml and also with sample valid XML data, because bad formatting in comments

Comment: thanks a lot ! should I also explore xml parsers or this will work fine ?

Comment: @saimkhan - I think best should first seen how looks valid xml, unfortuantely `TURBINE: GAS ; MAKE: M/S HITACHI ; MODEL: H-25` is not valid XML

Comment: Hey so i just figured the data is missing several key names, instead of this : ```TURBINE: GAS ; MAKE: M/S HITACHI ; MODEL: H-25``` I first need to modify it to ```ITEM : TURBINE; ??? : GAS ; MAKE: M/S HITACHI ; MODEL: H-25```

Comment: @saimkhan - I cannot see difference :(

Comment: I added "ITEM" in front of TURBINE and "???" in front of "GAS" sorry im a newbie. OR can I Standardize this ? i know what to name the column heads explicitly. like can i specify a particular format or something

Comment: @saimkhan - I think it should working also nice, only get some missing values in output data. Test it if use `L = ['AAA:a;B:b;C:c;D:d', 'A:a1;B:b1;C:c1;D:d1']`

Comment: Getting Error : ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required. Like I said data is missing some Key names which i need to add before running this. ```[Turbine]``` should be changed to ```[item : turbine]``` like this

Comment: @saimkhan - I understand, how many is values without `:` ?

Comment: I cant really say... sometimes 1 sometimes more, need a general solution

Comment: @saimkhan - tested and problem is here how python know column name for this problematic values if there is a lot of them? So added solution for first column is `item0`, then `item1`...